# to find answers in (the?) literature

Tags: meaning, articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

What is the different meanings of these two phrases?

> - to find answers in literature
> - to find answers in **the** literature

Is one just better/more correct than the other or are they meaning two different things?

Comment: I advise you to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer. And since it's the weekend, perhaps more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'The literature' defines what literature is under consideration. Usually it would refer to professional journals containing learned papers under peer review. What exactly is defined, depends on who is talking.

A doctor referring to 'the literature' will mean *The Lancet* and suchlike periodicals. Whilst a chemist will be referring to *Scientific American* and associated publications which deal with Chemistry.

Whereas 'literature' refers to all literature available - books, periodicals and today would include, I suspect, what is generally available on the internet.

Comment: So a Doctor referring to 'the literature' will mean scientific literature and the same Doctor referring to 'literature' will mean literature in general, including everything from Cicero to Shakespeare and beyond?

Comment: Also, *literature* on its own refers to *writings*, typically the classics of English Literature.

Comment: Your capitalisation is still non-standard.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Non-cap was due to finger trouble; now sorted.

Comment: No it's not. People proficient in chemistry are chemists, and doctors are no more venerable in the main than dentists.

Comment: Then it is a bad habit of mine which I must curtail . . .  and edit.